# PHP error on local server install

Tags: php, errors, installation

I'm trying to install an existing Wordpress website on my local server (Mamp). When I open the site in my browser it's all white. If I activate WP_DEBUG I've got this PHP error :

*Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=15) state=0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/gla/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 5318*

*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'T' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/www/gla/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 5318*

I've been installing and using Wordpress many times but it's the first time I see so. Is it a problem of PHP version?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of PHP and WordPress are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Just needed a fresh install from Wordpress and it works like a charm.